# Url rewrite with php

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-routing

What's wrong with this htaccess?
I'm trying to redirect everything that has a question mark like
"www.mysite.com/?bla=bla"
to
"www.mysite.com/router.php?bla=bla

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([\w]{1,7})$ short.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w]+)\.html$ html/$1.html [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w]+)\.php$ php/$1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^\?(.+)$ router.php?$1 [L]
```

Each rule works except for the last one, which returns me a:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Comment: This is off topic, and your question has nothing to do with PHP.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access the querystring inside a `RewriteRule`.  Instead, use `RewriteCond` to match it.  Using the `?` in the position you have it treats it as a special character for the regular expression.

Instead use:

```
# Prevent redirect loop
# Place above all other rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Non-empty querystring goes to router
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)
# Rewrite to router appending existing querystring (QSA)
RewriteRule ^/?$ router.php [L,QSA]
```

#### Addendum:

Prevent the router from going into the php directory with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^router\.php
RewriteRule ^([\w]+)\.php$ php/$1.php [L]
```

Comment: The redirect works: the problem is it goes recursively into the third statements, which points to the php folder. But this php file is in the root directory. How do I stop each condition I have to not be recursively called? Already googling

Comment: @hysoka44 See loop prevention added above.

Comment: Thanks michael, but it seems to be not working. Shouldn't the "prevent" section be on the top of the htaccess before every other rewriteurl?

Comment: @hysoka44 Yes it should - I assumed that was implied, sorry for not being clear.

Comment: It doesn't work either that way, it still goes into the php folder condition.

Comment: @hysoka44 See addition above. You need a condition to guard router.php from being caught by the php/ rule